# What should one do if one thinks that someone is mass-voting them?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

If an anonymous person is mass-voting anyone's questions, what should one do?

Comment: So you are suspended minutes after posting this meta post, for voting irregularity.....

Comment: @ArcticChar How do you know that it is for voting irregularity?

Comment: @BeKind For some reason, their meta profile does not indicate the suspension reason. Their [main profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/979939/lol) does indicate that it is for voting irregularities.

Comment: @BeKind That can be found in the OP's main page [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/979939/lol). Basically "someone" upvoted more than 10 of their posts, and the votes are corrected several minutes ago.

Comment: What’s voting irregularities? Also, can I see my own set bounties on the “bountied questions” page? I think this is too trivial to be a question so just asking these two questions here.

Comment: Considering that serial voting related suspensions are completely manual according to [this Meta.SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857), it would seem that OP is suspended by a moderator, rather than by some automatic response.

Comment: @ArcticChar, do you mean to say that the user upvoted themselves? In this case, they would just stay quiet and wouldn't create this post.

Comment: @Dmitry - I think some people just like making a mess, and aren't trying to cleverly inflate their reputation. So "vote oddly and spam Meta" is one way they can have fun.

Comment: Interesting... post

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC, do I understand correctly that I can reliably cause suspension of any user by creating a bunch of accounts and mass-upvoting the user?

Comment: @Dmitry Moderators will very likely not suspend a user who is the target of unsolicited serial voting. I'm not a moderator on this site or any other site, but it is my understanding that they seek to find some degree of  proof that the accounts upvoting the target user are either solicited by the target user or controlled by the target user before issuing any suspensions. If they need help looking into it, they have channels through which they can ask Stack Exchange staff to assist.

Comment: @Dmitry - I don't know. The actions taken to deal with questionable voting, both automated and by-hand, seem to be kept deliberately obscure. It would be an interesting experiment to run, but I don't feel like creating extra work for moderators, and would probably agree with cancelling all the accounts of anyone who did try it.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, you shouldn't need to worry about anything. The system has a built-in vote correction script that runs periodically, and catches most types of serial voting (you may notice a ["Voting corrected"](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) entry in your reputation history.) This invalidates most instances of serial voting, both for up- and down-votes. It'll reverse reputation gain/loss and revoke the votes from the original user who cast them from their vote history. Most serial voting issues stop here, as only the recipient of this reversal is notified that such a reversal occurred (via their reputation history or achievements dropdown.)

If over 24 hours have passed since you experienced what you feel to be suspicious or targeted voting, you can [flag one of your posts for moderator attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/) and explain your findings/suspicions about serial voting occurring on your posts. Moderators have access to tools to see a degree of potential vote fraud. If they have enough evidence, they can escalate it to Stack Exchange staff so that they can manually invalidate the votes.

As to your current suspension... It seems that moderators were able to determine that an alternate account of yours had a long history of upvoting your questions. There's an entry in your reputation history that a user was removed and that you lost 120 reputation. That's 12 upvotes across 15 posts. A suspension wouldn't have been issued if there wasn't found to be some form of coordination between your account and the deleted account. My advice to you, and others, is just... Don't do that. You should have a moderator message in your inbox that explains what happened and why moderators suspended your account.

In the [Vote up privilege info page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up), there's a good ([recently added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379261/622284)) section that  explains:

> Posts should be voted on based on the content in the post rather than the person who wrote it. Voting for specific people, whether you know them or not, can negatively impact our ranking system. Here are some examples of common cases that should be avoided:
>
> - Repeatedly upvoting several of a user's posts to say "thanks" for one great answer.
> - Repeatedly upvoting posts created by people you know because you know them often friends, family, or coworkers.
> - Targeting a specific user with votes for any other reason.
>
> In cases where voting patterns appear to be targeted, the votes are likely to be reversed, either by automatic systems or manually following an investigation by the staff, which will cause a loss of reputation earned from these votes.